# How risky is calling a virtual method in the constructor of an EntityTypeConfiguration<T>?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, oop

I have a base class for all entity classes:

```
public class XTimeEntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity> : EntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity> where TEntity : XTimeEntity
{
  public XTimeEntityTypeConfiguration()
  {
      this.HasKey(t => t.Id);
      this.Property(t => t.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);        
      this.Ignore(t => t.IsActive);
  }
}
```

Now I would like to make this default behaviour overridable, because in some entity classes logic is needed to determine how it is done, e.g. which property is the key. I also want to make other parts of the config, and I can't override a constructor, so was thinking of calling virtual methods from the constructor, fully aware of the smell of this, but also fairly confident the inheritance depth from this base class will nearly always only be one, i.e. one derived implementation per entity. My proposed base class would be something like:

```
public abstract class XTimeEntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity> : EntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity> where TEntity : XTimeEntity
{
  protected XTimeEntityTypeConfiguration()
  {
    ConfigureProperties();
    ConfigureRelationships();
    ConfigureTableMapping();
    ConfigureKey();
    ConfigureColumnMappings();
  }

  protected virtual void ConfigureKey()
  {
    this.HasKey(t => t.Id);
    this.Property(t => t.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
  }

  protected virtual void ConfigureTableMapping()
  {
    var plurals = PluralizationService.CreateService(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
    this.ToTable(plurals.Pluralize(GetType().Name));
  }

  protected virtual void ConfigureColumnMappings() { }
  protected virtual void ConfigureProperties() { }
  protected virtual void ConfigureRelationships() { }
  protected virtual void ConfigureIgnores()
  {
    this.Ignore(t => t.IsActive);
  }
}
```

And a derived instance:

```
public class ActivityMap : XTimeEntityTypeConfiguration<Activity>
{
  public ActivityMap() : base() {}

  protected override void ConfigureProperties()
  {
    base.ConfigureProperties();
    this.Property(t => t.Name)
      .IsRequired()
      .HasMaxLength(30);
  }

  protected override void ConfigureColumnMappings()
  {
    base.ConfigureColumnMappings();
    this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("ACT_CODEID");
  }

  protected override void ConfigureTableMapping()
  {
    this.ToTable("ACTIVITY");
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you don't need inheritance here at all.

Comment: Pray, expound on your assertion. This reduces code to that in actual mapping classes that use unique Key properties, and ignore more properties than the normal one, and that don't map their name to a plural table name.

Comment: I mean, you may keep the base class in it's initial state, and use it only if the particular entity fits it. Otherwise, use `EntityTypeConfiguration`. You won't save much lines of code with the second approach (virtual methods). How many sort of entities do you have?

Comment: You'll be OK as long as you remember to call the base methods when necessary, but that's easily forgotten.

Comment: @Dennis Ah, I see. There are a great deal of lines of code to save, as I have 245 entities.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you would be better of using the [Decorator Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) here. You can leave the configuration behaviors to the decorators, so you don't get a virtual mess :)

In this case, use a decorator base class, and derive from it, something like:

```
public abstract class EntityConfigurationBehavior
{
    public abstract void Configure<TEntity>(EntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity> config);
}

public class DefaultConfigurationBehavior : EntityConfigurationBehavior
{
    public override void Configure<TEntity>(EntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity> config)
    {
        config.HasKey(t => t.Id);
        config.Property(t => t.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);        
        config.Ignore(t => t.IsActive);
    }
}
```

In your configuration class, have a protected field or property with the configuration:

```
public abstract class XTimeEntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity> : EntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity> where TEntity : XTimeEntity
{
    // [...]

    protected EntityConfigurationBehavior ConfigurationBehavior { get; set; }

    // [...]
}
```

Now you can call set it up like that:

```
public class ActivityMap : XTimeEntityTypeConfiguration<Activity>
{
    public ActivityMap() : base() 
    {
        ConfigurationBehavior = new DefaultConfigurationBehavior(this);
    }
}
```

If you need more configuration options, you can always create more behaviors, or if that gets too messy, make a list of behaviors that you can configure. I didn't make *EntityConfigurationBehavior* generic, since you are looking for a way to configure all **common** properties. You can configure the properties specific to *Activity* in the ActivityMap itself.

Comment: Good idea. I'll try it out soon.

Comment: The deviations from the standard base-concrete class behaviour are only in the constructors. No other methods exist by default. Would using Decorator to change the behaviour of a constructor not be quite difficult?  Unless only in the decorator do I factor the behaviours out of the constructor, as I have done in my class above.

Comment: You create a base class for the mapping behaviors. Then you can inherit, for example a GeneratedIdBehavior. The XTimeEntityTypeConfiguration class has a protected behavior as a property, which you set in the constructor of ActivityMap. I could elaborate, if necessary.

Comment: Maybe elaborate just a little please. I have an idea what you mean, but very vague.

Comment: Just out of interest: did that solve your problem? :)

Comment: I haven't yet. I am looking at modifying the EF Reverse Engineering template, but I can't afford to start again on this project.